# JAXB eclipse error: There's no JAXB 2.2 API in the classpath

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jaxb

I am trying to generate java classes from xsd. I added to my library the following two files: **com.sun.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201004141950.jar** and **com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0.jar**, but it still gives me an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: There's no JAXB 2.2 API in the classpath
at com.sun.tools.xjc.ClassLoaderBuilder.createProtectiveClassLoader(ClassLoaderBuilder.java:82)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCFacade.main(XJCFacade.java:65)
```

What can be the problem? When I created the project I chose JAXB 2.1 with jre target runtime. What do I need to include to make it run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to include the jaxb-impl.jar library in your project. You can download one for example from here: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.4/jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar

If you're using Maven, you can include this as a dependency, otherwise download the file and add it as a library in your project.

If you need a different version of the library, move up one directory in the link that I added above, you can find other versions there as well.

If you want to automate the class generation, since you're changing the schema on a regular basis, you should automate the process, e.g through Maven.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand any of this. The JAXB Reference Implementation ("RI") has been included with the JDK since Java 6.

https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Which_JAXB_RI_is_included_in_which_JDK_.html

So, given this, why do you need to add any external libraries ?